# Java ArrayList, generics, and late binding

Tags: java

Is it true to say that Java generics are all late binding? Is an ArrayList<Something> type ignored until runtime?

Why is it?

Answer (score 7):

> Is it true to say that Java generics are all late binding?

No.

> Is an ArrayList<Something> type ignored until runtime?

No.

> Why is it?

It isn't.

Comment: Might work on a test with these sort of questions, but without further explanation, it lacks as an answer. (I have avoided saying anything about the question(s) ;-)

Comment: (not about generics) I would appreciate if _you_ take a look at this meta discussion: [interviews with remarkable community contributors](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104045/interviews-with-remarkable-community-contributors)

Comment: This is the perfect answer for the given question(s). If the original author wanted different answers he would need to ask different questions.

Comment: @pst Questions like this that are just based on false premisses don't merit serious consideration IMO, in fact they verge on trolling. I answered all three of his questions, scored 3 out of 3 too.

Comment: @gnat I did one of those as 'Contributor of the Month' to the Sun Java forums last year. Happy to provide it to you offline if you can't find it.

Comment: @EJP sure I remember that's why I was interested in your take on a similar idea for Stack Overflow. BTW these interviews are still online, there's a link to them in the question at meta

Comment: @gnat it's a good idea for sure. Not sure what selection procedure would work in this context: at Sun it was just someone's executive fiat.

Answer (score 4):

> Is an ArrayList<Something> type ignored until runtime?

It's rather the other way around.

Java Generics are taken into account at compile time. At runtime, there is *erasure*.

- Find more details in this chapter in the Java online tutorial: [Type Erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) *"When a generic type is instantiated, the compiler translates those types by a technique called type erasure — a process where the compiler removes all information related to type parameters and type arguments within a class or method..."*

Comment: Except the compiler leaves in all the information it needs to compile further code, so you can get a lot of the generic information. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey yup, [ParameterizedType](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) etc :)

Answer (score 3):

Generics and late binding doesn't have anything to do with each other.

The ArrayList type is not ignored at runtime.  Its generic parameter type is often ignored through type erasure. This is done for backward compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, could Peter explain a tad more ?

Comment: I don't know what you don't know. ;) Can you say what your doubt is? BTW there are millions of pages on generics.

Answer (score 2):

No, Java generics are not late binding. But to quote the official Java documentation from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html):

> To implement generics, the Java compiler applies type erasure to:
>   Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or
>   Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode,
>   therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.